# primitive operations with short integers

Tags: c++11, integer

Consider a code

```
int16_t x = 1;
int16_t y = 1;

auto v = x + y;

int16_t w = x + y;

cout << sizeof(v) << endl << sizeof(w) << endl;
```

where I used `#include <cstdint>` for fixed size integers.
The output is

```
 4
 2
```

Why the sizes of v and w are different, and how do I make the sizes of integers to be fixed during primitive operations ?

Note that, the result for v will be the same if I use a 8-bit integer type instead of int16_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast:

> Prvalues of small integral types (such as `char` may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`). In particular, **arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments**, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value.

[emphasis mine; link removed]

So there is no way to do what you want.

The reason that `int16_t w = x + y;` works is that it does a conversion back to `int16_t` at the end. From the same source:

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise the result is implementation-defined. (Note that this is different from signed integer arithmetic overflow, which is undefined)

[link removed]

---

**Edited to add:** That said, I should mention that there is no real reason to do what you want, either. It's true that `int16_t w = x + y;` means `int16_t w = static_cast<int16_t>( static_cast<int>(x) + static_cast<int>(y) );` rather than performing 16-bit addition to begin with; but the result is the same either way. The only difference is that if `x + y` is outside the range of 16-bit integers, then `int16_t w = x + y;` will still be reasonably well-behaved (giving an implementation-defined result), because `+` itself is not triggering overflow.